# JQuery Colorbox Won't Close in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, colorbox

we are using jQuery ColorBox a few places on our site, and folks cannot close the popup window in IE8. Works fine in Firefox.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks, Amy (jQuery Newbie)

Example of photo gallery page: http://matsinc.com/photogallery/woven-vinyl-flooring

Here's the code on the photo gallery page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        // Tool Tip
        //$("a[title]").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
        var cb_height = '566px';

        if ($j.browser.msie && !$j.support.opacity) {
            if ($j.browser.version == 7) {
                cb_height = '598px';
            }
        }

        var cb_html = '<div class="cbox-gallery"><h2></h2><img src="" alt="" /><div class="cbox-footer2"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.miprojectlibrary.com">Visit MI Project Library</a><br />Collect, distribute and download high resolution photos and swatches.</div></div>';
        //colorbox for Photo Gallery
        $j("a[rel='cb-gallery']").colorbox({
            opacity: 0.5,
            current: '{current} of {total}',
            close: 'Close',
            html: cb_html,
            height: cb_height,
            scrolling: false,
            onComplete: function() {
                var title = $j(this).attr('title');
                var img = $j(this).attr('href');
                $j('.cbox-gallery h2').text(title);
                $j('.cbox-gallery img').attr({
                    'src': img,
                    'alt': title
                });
                $j('.cbox-gallery .download').attr('href', img);
                //$.colorbox.resize();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me too it was not closing on IE8, I was using colorbox 1.3.20 and jquery 1.7.1, I upgraded jquery to 1.8.1 and now it closes on IE8 :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say upgrade jQuery to 1.4.3+ or downgrade colorbox to 1.3.18.

[From the colorbox page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), it states that your current version of colorbox (1.3.19) was tested with jQuery 1.4.3+ and you are using 1.4.2.

> Current version: 1.3.19 ( Released under the MIT License | Github | Changelog )
>
> Tested in: jQuery 1.4.3+ in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9, Opera 11.
> For older versions of jQuery (1.3.2+), use version 1.3.18

I'm getting a jquery error when viewing from IE8
[image]